# ¿Cómo modifico una línea concreta de un fichero indicando el número de línea?

Tags: bash, sed

Ejecuto este comando para cambiar justo esa línea, pero no modifica nada:

```
sed -i '25c\anonymous_enable=YES' /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Hice una copia en otro directorio y sí pudo cambiarlo aunque la copia de vsftpd.conf se encontraba en el mismo directorio, así que no sé si es por la ruta o algo que no puedo modificar el archivo original.

Este comando debo de ejecutarlo desde un script.c con system(); pero por ahora solo desde el shell he querido hacerlo y no funciona.

¿Qué es lo que me falta?

Comment: Es importante que describas cómo es el archivo, qué quieres cambiar y qué no está funcionando. Si no, será difícil ayudarte. Por otra parte, es bastante sensible modificar ficheros de este tipo "a mano", por lo que por lo menos deberías hacer un backup antes del proceso! (`sed -i.bak '...' fichero` por ejemplo te hace el backup al hacer la modificación)

Comment: gracias, ya hice un backup aunque no de esa forma, lo que quiero es cambiar la linea 25 y poner "anonymous_enable=YES", pero no se modifica nada al ejecutar el comando

Comment: ¿Pero quieres sustituir todo lo que hay en esa línea por "anonymous_enable=YES"` o mantener algo de lo que había? Siempre es bueno [edit] para explicar mejor en la propia pregunta.

Comment: Sustituir todo, es por ello que hasta donde vi se usa el flag (c), me funciono con una copia del archivo en la misma carpeta, pero no con la que esta en esa direccion

Comment: A ver, es bien curioso. ¿Tú opción no sólo debería funcionar, sino que lo hace pero sólo con un archivo de respaldo? ¿Tú usuario tiene permisos de escritura sobre ese archivo?

Answer (score 2):

No conocía el parámetro `c` para sed y al probarlo en OSX me ha dado problemas. Dado que no ofreces más datos y el más estándar y portable es el `s/busca/sustituye/`, usemos este:

```
sed 'Ns/.*/nuevo valor/' fichero
```

Donde `N` es el número de línea y `nuevo valor` el nuevo contenido que vas a incluir.

En tu caso:

```
sed -i.bak '25s/.*/anonymous_enable=YES' /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Nótese el uso de `-i.bak` que realizará un fichero de backup, que nunca es mala idea.